# Analog Devices Gyro: What are these pins for?

Tags: pcb, analog, gyro, bga

I am after some guidance please.

I am designing a basic PCB which includes an ADXRS646 gyro. This is the first time I have designed a circuit with a BGA package and I do not understand the purpose of the following pins, or whether I need to include them in my 'breakout' (it will be connected to an Arduino for debugging purposes):

- Output Amp Summing Junction (SUMJ)
- Charge Pump Capacitor pins (CP1/2/3/4)

See [here](http://www.analog.com/en/products/mems/mems-gyroscopes/adxrs646.html).

I had ignored them (just added capacitors), but I notice that some evaluation boards from Analog Devices connect these to break-out pins.

Any guidance on their purpose would be useful please. I just need to use this gyro for basic rate-out operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charge pump pins are simply attachment points for the external capacitors the gyro needs to function. There's no reason to break them out on a breakout; just connect the recommended capacitors.

The summing junction pin is another pin for external capacitance, but in this case it allows adjustment of the lowpass filter frequency on the output. A larger capacitor means a sharper lowpass filter. Depending on your use-case, you may either want to include a capacitor and not break it out, for fixed frequency operation, leave out the capacitor and require users of your breakout to add it, or include a minimum sized one and allow users to add more in parallel if they want a lower cutoff frequency. The choice is up to you.

Comment: That is very useful, and thank you for being so prompt. Can you briefly explain how I would go about determining the size of the SUMJ capacitor? I am unsure what you mean by 'frequency' in this case.

Comment: For information, this device will be subjected to aerodynamic loads after 'launch' and during freefall, but will not see mechnically induced vibration.

Comment: @Abesood This is described in section "Setting Bandwidth" in the datasheet. The output signal voltage depends on the rate of rotation, but if the rate of rotation is changing, you have an AC signal. Filtering allows you to ignore very high frequency changes that might be, say, due to vibration, while still registering low frequency changes like deliberate turns.

Comment: Thank you Nick and apoloies for missing that and appreciate your patience. The datasheet recommends an RC low pass filter of 3.3kOhm + 22nF in series. Would these go in series between SUMJ and RATEOUT? Any research I do on RC LP filters puts them between the output and ground (nothing mentions SUMJ...).

Comment: @Abesood The filter they're referring to is an optional external one that you'd put between the IC's output pin and your device. The datasheet also mentions that you can add extra resistance in series with Cout, but that's also optional.